# How to minify your jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, minify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to minify jquery files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678471/how-to-minify-jquery-files)

Are there any tools, which can minify jQuery code, like jQuery.com do it itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try Google's [Closure tools](http://code.google.com/closure/). There is an [online minifier service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) in the past. It's easy to use and it does a really good job.

Answer (score 0):

yui compressor: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

It can compress javascript and css.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the Ajax Minifier from Microsoft:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxMinDocumentation.ashx

You can even add it as a build job to a asp.net project and it will minify any javascript or css everytime it publishes.  That way, you don't have to keep up with two references and still get readable versions to debug with...

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Visual Studio, Chirpy is the best.