# Optimize jQuery Function 

Tags: jquery, query-optimization

It's possible to optimize and minify this sample function? How could I do it?

```
$(function () {
    $("#options").change(function () {
        var message_index = $("#options").val();
        if (message_index == 0) {

            $("#display_image").show();
            $("#display_flash, #display_youtube, #display_google").hide();

        } else if (message_index == 1) {

            $("#display_flash").show();
            $("#display_image, #display_youtube, #display_google").hide();

        } else if (message_index == 2) {

            $("#display_youtube").show();
            $("#display_image, #display_flash, #display_google").hide();

        } else if (message_index == 3) {

            $("#display_google").show();
            $("#display_image, #display_flash, #display_youtube").hide();

        } else {

            $("#display_image, #display_flash, #display_youtube, #display_google").hide();

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function () {

    var $displays = $("#display_flash, #display_youtube, #display_google, #display_image"),
        toShow = ['image','flash','youtube','google'];
    $("#options").change(function () {
        $displays.hide();
        $("#display_"+toShow[$(this).val()]).show();
    });

});
```

Comment: here compressed (YUI) => `$(function(){$("#options").change(function(){var b=$("#options").val();var a=["image","flash","youtube","google"];$("#display_flash, #display_youtube, #display_google, #display_image").hide();$("#display_"+a[b]).show()})});`

Comment: +1 I like it. I would add in a check whether `message_index` is in the array, you can avoid an unnecessary jQuery call.

Comment: Yes, well.. it's something I left for the OP :D

Answer (score 2):

Not really much optimisation, but certainly cleaner IMO:

```
$(function () {
    $("#options").change(function () {
        // hide everything
        $("#display_image, #display_flash, #display_youtube, #display_google").hide();

        switch ($("#options").val()) {
            case 0:
                $("#display_image").show();
                break;
            case 1:
                $("#display_flash").show();
                break;
            case 2:
                $("#display_youtube").show();
                break;
            case 3:
                $("#display_google").show();
                break;
        }
    });

});
```

To minify, use http://jscompress.com/

Comment: i would also put your hides together ohh and get rid of the var just put it in the switch

Answer (score 1):

If you want to minify that code, try putting it into here - http://www.minifyjavascript.com/

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, you could do something like this:

```
$("#options").change(function () {
    var message_index = $("#options").val();
    var elemIds=[
        '#display_image', 
        '#display_flash', 
        '#display_youtube', 
        '#display_google'];
    $(elemIds.join(',')).hide();
    if (elemIds[message_index]) {
        $(elemIds[message_index]).show();
    }
});
```

You haven't provided the markup you're running this on, even further optimizations would be possible based on that. Maybe adding a common class for those showable elements. If the elements are in the right order in the markup (same as the `message_index` order), you can go even further with optimizations.

For minification, there are several tools to use, the others have provided you some.

Comment: I like It. If you'll write a book I'll definitely but it. Thank you

Comment: @MiniNaim If I ever write a book, it won't be about programming :). There are more qualified people for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get ideas from:

[Minify jQuery based js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841253/javascript-good-tool-to-minify-jquery-based-js-files)

[How to minify jquery files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678471/how-to-minify-jquery-files)

Answer (score 0):

replace your if statement with a switch statement

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Question: How could I do it?

Answer: replace your if statement with a switch statement